# In Mapreduce, I am wondering there is some way to use 2 csv files using java

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

Basically, I am trying to use 2 csv files, so first input csv file will be inputed by an user, but second csv file I just defined in the mapper code, so is there some way when the mapper keeps running, to get some value in second csv file which is defined in the mapper class without some loop? The reason I am doing this is I want to make some key value of mapper using a value in second csv file and two values in the first mapper.
Thank you so much for any help and your time.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;



    public class StubMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

        private Text outkey = new Text();
        //private MinMaxCountTuple outTuple = new MinMaxCountTuple();


        @Override
        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {





            try {

                String csvFile = "/workspace/project/src/subject.csv";


                if(csvFile.toString().startsWith("BibNumber"))
                {
                    return;
                }

                String subject[] = csvFile.toString().split(",");
                String BookName = subject[1];

                if(value.toString().startsWith("BibNumber"))
                {
                    return;
                }


                String data[] = value.toString().split(",");
                String BookType = data[2];
                String DateTime = data[5];


                SimpleDateFormat frmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

                Date creationDate = frmt.parse(DateTime);
                frmt.applyPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String dateTime = frmt.format(creationDate);

                outkey.set(BookName + ", " + BookType + ", " + dateTime);

                //outUserId.set(userId);
                context.write(outkey, new IntWritable(1));

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: `csvFile.toString()` doesn't read any file content. Also `/workspace` looks like a local filesystem, which isn't an HDFS location that mapreduce would be required to read

Comment: You need to implement the `setup` method in the Mapper. Otherwise, you're trying to read the CSV for every single record the mapper sees

Comment: What would setup function form look like? Thanks for letting know me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need something like this

```
 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {

    private final String csvFile = "/workspace/project/src/subject.csv";
    private List<String> csvData = new ArrayList<>();

    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
          FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
          Path p = new Path(csvFile); // this file must be on HDFS 
          // read csvFile from fs
          // store CSV records in some field 
    }
```

Inside the map method, you loop over `csvData`

Comment: So, whenever program runs, the words have to be grabbed from that function, right? But, I am still confused how it can happen, after declaration of FileSystem, what do I have to write more? Sorry for keeping asking you !

Comment: You need to actually read the hdfs file into a variable https://stackoverflow.com/a/14574296/2308683